# How to convert JSON response adding hours to current date in Swift

Tags: json, swift, date, hour

I am getting JSON response like this in console

```
 JSON: {
result =     {

 "product_marchant" =             {
            fname = Seller1;
            id = 2;
            lname = One1;
            "order_arrives" = 48;
        };
    }
    }
```

**servicecall code:**

```
fileprivate func serviceCall(){
let param = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
             "params": ["product_id" : productID
    ]] as [String : Any]

APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, vc: self, url: getUrl(of: .product_details), header: header) {(responseData) in
    if responseData.error != nil{
        print(responseData.error)
        self.view.makeToast(NSLocalizedString("Something went wrong!", comment: ""))
    }else{
        self.detailsDB = ProductDetailsData(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        
        let var date = detailsDB.result.product_marchant.product_marchant
        
        print("JSON value \(date)")
    }
}
}
```

**0/p**

```
JSON value  48
```

I need to add the number of hours to the current date, so is shown as `Monday June, 28` (today is 26th June).

How do I do this?

The JSON value returned is an Optional String.

Comment: How could 48 be interpreted as Monday june, 28? I can guess how but _you_ need to explain the logic in the question so it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: Where does a guy named APIReqeustManager come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the '48' value that you derive from `order_arrives` is the number of hours to add to current date.

```
let hours = Int(detailsDB.result.product_marchant.product.marchant!) ?? 0

let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = Date()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full

if let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hours, to: today) {
    print("JSON Value: \(formatter.string(from: date))")
}
```

**Output (as of today, 26th June):**

```
"JSON Value: Monday, June 28, 2021\n"
```

Comment: thank you.. my sr also suggested me to do like this..

Comment: but here the error is: `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Comment: here `value: hours` bcz `let hours` is string

Comment: Wrap it in an Int - `let hours = Int(detailsDB.result.product_marchant.product.marchant!) ?? 0`

Comment: if its `24hrs` then i need to show `Tomorrow june, 27`... how to do that.. could u plz help

Comment: The above code will calculate the future date with any amount of hours you assign.  If hours = 24 then it will show tomorrow's date.

Comment: yes instead of tomorrow's date i need like this `Tomorrow june, 27` if hours == "24".. how?

Comment: `if calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date) { print("Tomorrow \(formatter.string(from: date))") } else { print(formatter.string(from: date))}`

Comment: You can change the way the date is formatted, by using `formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, d"`